# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline - Pass environment variable to docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps. This is pulling a docker image from an ACR and publishing to a Web App (linux container). All works fine (container is published & runs as expected), however I can't seem to pass in any custom environment variables at runtime to the container.

**Release pipeline**

In the pipeline 'Deploy Azure App Service' under the variable tab, I have added, `MY_ENV test01` and then under 'App settings' I have added

-e MY_ENV

The release is published and the image is updated ok.

**Container Logs**

The docker run command in the logs does not have the environment variable
I was expected -e MY_ENV in the command, but it missing.

Anyone know how to pass an ENV variable to a docker container at runtime via an Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the way you are passing the App settings is wrong in your deploy app service pipeline task `-e MY_ENV`. Instead just directly add `-MY_ENV test01` as part of your app settings. and it should be available as part of your environment. see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

[image]

If this still fails, you can pass/set your environment variables as follows : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-environment-variables

You can run this Azure CLI command as part of your devops pipeline (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I didn't need to use the 'variables' tab. Worked fine using the first scenario as above, setting -MY_ENV test01 in AppSettings. I was able to log into the container and confirm the ENV variable was present. It doesnt seem to change the docker run command, but all good, as present when required from inside container.