# How to pass environment variables during program runtime for docker container in azure

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-repos

I have my connection string inside a .env file, which I don't commit into the git repo. And I have my app up and running on Azure.

So the way my app works is, when I push my code to Github, Azure Container Registry will build the image on the committed code, and then Azure App Service is going to pull and build a container for my app.

So my question is, how do I pass that connection string to the Docker container? What I could do is put the .env file into the git repo, but I don't think I should put it up there.

Comment: This has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894774/azure-devops-release-pipeline-pass-environment-variable-to-docker-container/67895404#67895404

Comment: ok that works. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Rimaz Mohommed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4546132/rimaz-mohommed). Posting comment section discussion into Answer section to help other community users.

**Couple of approaches**

Add the Variables directly as part of the app settings and it should be available as part of your app environment.
Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

You can pass/set your environment variables by [Configure environment variables.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-environment-variables)

You can run this Azure CLI command as part of your devops pipeline (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops)